# Simplifying Boolean equations

Tags: boolean-algebra

I can simplify this using Kmaps, but can't figure out how to using boolean algebra. If anyone could show me the steps I'd really appreciate it. F=A.B+A'.B.C'+B.C.
I get F=b(A+A'.C'+C) Not sure what to do after.

Answer (score 1):

Expand `A` to `AC + AC'` and `C` to `AC + A'C`, then simplify again.

Comment: how do i get rid of A'.C'

Comment: It combines with `AC'` and/or `A'C`.